# Query to select newly added records only

Tags: mysql, record

As I am new to mysql, let me clear this doubt. how to write a query to find/select the latest added records only?

Example: 
Consider a Table, which is daily added certain amount of records. Now the table contain 1000 records. And the total 1000 records are taken out for some performance. After sometimes table is added 100 records. Now I would like take the remain 100 only from the 1100 to do some operation. How to do it?

(For example only, I have given the numbers, But originally I don't know the last updated count and the newly added)

Here My table contain three columns Sno, time, data. where Sno is indexed as primary key.

Sample table:

```
| sno | time                | data    |

|   1 | 2012-02-27 12:44:07 |     100 |

|   2 | 2012-02-27 12:44:07 |     120 |

|   3 | 2012-02-27 12:44:07 |     140 |

|   4 | 2012-02-27 12:44:07 |     160 |

|   5 | 2012-02-27 12:44:07 |     180 |


|   6 | 2012-02-27 12:44:07 |     160 |

|   7 | 2012-02-28 13:00:35 |     100 |

|   8 | 2012-03-02 15:23:25 |     160 |
```

Answer (score 6):

Add `TIMESTAMP` field with `'ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'` option, and you will be able to find last added or last edited records.

[Automatic Initialization and Updating for TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/timestamp-initialization.html).

Answer (score 0):

Create table as below

```
Create table sample
(id int auto_increment primary key,
time timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
data nvarchar(100)
);
```

then query as

```
select * from sample order by time desc limit 1
```

Comment: Here you have mention only one record. Actually, how to find the no of record added newly?

Comment: There should be a timeframe in which you want to find the records `select * from sample where time > $yourTime`