# mysql - Query to display record just added

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two pages. One is a form that I use to simply input data that will be sent to my database and the second page that actually takes the data inputted into the form and sends it to the database and is supposed to display the information that I've just added.

Everything works fine, however I'm struggling with the query slightly. What I need it to do is display all the information for the last data inputted to the database.

The query I currently have just displays the data with the highest ID:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Results ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1";
```

So as an example I would be left with the following information after completing my form:

```
Success! Data being saved: 
ID = 900    Amount = 206    Date = 2016-12-26
```

This is obviously just showing the data with the highest ID, but since the ID and all the data fluctuates, I need it to just show the data that has just been inputted.

I came accross this: [Query to select newly added records only.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9531628/query-to-select-newly-added-records-only) But I don't believe this soultion to be viable as the database is external and I don't want to be creating new tables.

I was thinking that it might be possible to assign a hidden value to each newly added record via the query. e.g. New 1, New 2, New 3 etc. Then printing the latest record for New. However, I couldn't find anything on how to do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can have 3 pages; Page 1: Input, Page 2: View Inputted, Page 3: View all. After inputting  u can use GET and send the id to the View Inputted page

Comment: Your current implementation also has a flaw.  Consider multiple users entering data at the same time, you can't guarantee that the ID returend from your select query produces the id for that transaction.  Use LAST_INSERT_ID to get the last id from that transaction

Comment: `LAST_INSERT_ID()` ought to work.

Comment: Thanks guys, will look into that now.

Comment: Seeing the answers below, some appear to be feeding off [my comment posted much earlier than those...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41385037/mysql-query-to-display-record-just-added#comment69972399_41385037) *\*sigh\** and you're welcome ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sorry, I didn't see your comment :( I can vote to delete my answer if you want to add yours as answer.

Comment: @ICE I always admired honesty. Keep your answer, yours gives a lot of detail.

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone. Using `LAST_INSERT_ID()` sorted my problem. Thank you @Fred-ii- and @ICE :) Greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @thickguru You're welcome. ICE's answer was better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use this method to have very correct value:

1. Input form must send to another file that do inserting (we call it here insert.php)
2. insert.php must insert the data after validation and after that you can fetch the last ID number from database. Depending on the method you are working with it can be different. for example if you are using PDO you can get it by [PDO::lastInsertId](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php)
3. after getting the ID you need to forward it to the viewing or editing page. for example `view.php?id=LastInsertId`. This forward have some reasons:

   - Codes can be cleaner.
   - We prevent refresh and resend inserting. for example if you do inserting inside view.php and user hit F5 to refresh the page, The insertion happening again.

This is the whole idea. you can use this method for only one page:

1. page.php?do=new
2. page.php?do=insert
3. forward to the page.php?do=view&id=lastInsertID

Answer (score 0):

why you trying to get just inputted data from database? you can do it using HTTP POST/GET method easily.just send data as parameters and show them in second page.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the data you are inserting, you don't need to run a query to get it back from the database again, you could just ensure that the query was successful and display the data directly. Anyways:
You can get the insert ID from the last insert using the MySQLi object. For example:

```
$sql = "<your insert statement>"
$conn->query($sql);
$last_id = $conn->insert_id; //Id of the row you just inserted
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Results WHERE id=$last_id";
```

This is assuming you do the insert in the same page that you display the result.